# How to attach promise to my $each

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I'm having a problem to attach a promise to my `$each` loop. `getTemplate` is an async function. I would like to feed all templates within each, collect them into `getAppsTmp` variable and insert them below. At the moment the variable after then is empty.

```
var getAppsTmp
      var promise = $.each(addons, function (i, addon) {
        if (addon.isApp === true && addon.appLaunchUrl) {
          console.log(addon)
          var bestIcon = addon.icons.length - 1

          getTemplate('app-link', function (tmp) {
            getAppsTmp += tmp({
              appId: addon.id,
              appLaunch: addon.launchType,
              appName: addon.shortName,
              appUrl: addon.appLaunchUrl,
              appIcon: addon.icons[bestIcon].url
            })
          })
        }
      })
      $.when(promise).then(function () {
        $(modalId + ' .content').html(getAppsTmp)
      })
```

if I do this way everything works but I need to append them all in one go:

```
getTemplate('app-link', function (tmp) {
    getAppsTmp = tmp({
    appId: addon.id,
    appLaunch: addon.launchType,
    appName: addon.shortName,
    appUrl: addon.appLaunchUrl,
    appIcon: addon.icons[bestIcon].url
    })
 $(modalId + ' .content').append(getAppsTmp)
})
```

Comment: Just as an FYI - using native (or polyfilled) Promises makes the code (in my opinion) even cleaner - https://jsfiddle.net/b82z1fnz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.each` returns the array that you pass on the first argument instead of a promise.

If I get your question right, you might want to do something like this..

```
var getAppsTmp = '',
    deferreds = [];

$.each(addons, function(i, addon) {
  if (addon.isApp === true && addon.appLaunchUrl) {
    console.log(addon)

    var bestIcon = addon.icons.length - 1,
        deferred = $.Deferred();

    getTemplate('app-link', function(tmp) {
      getAppsTmp += tmp({
        appId: addon.id,
        appLaunch: addon.launchType,
        appName: addon.shortName,
        appUrl: addon.appLaunchUrl,
        appIcon: addon.icons[bestIcon].url
      });

      deferred.resolve();
    });

    deferreds.push(deferred);
  }
});

$.when.apply(null, deferreds).then(function () {
  $(modalId + ' .content').html(getAppsTmp);
});
```

The code above basically creates [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) objects, and store them into an array for each iteration of `addons`. then to resolve it after `getTemplate` is done.